# What is a 1-D np.array of dimension m?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a task and the output should be a "1-D np.array of dimension m" and I don't understand how a 1-D array can have m Dimension, it has 1 per definition ?

Comment: Looks like it means the size of the 1-D array is m

Comment: A better phrasing might be `a one dimensional array of size m`.  Shape will be a one element tulpe (m,)

Answer (score 1):

The word dimension can mean multiple things, in this case it means the size/length of the singular dimension, i.e. you can say an array has dimensions 2x2.

Therefore, a 1D array of dimension m is equivalent to a list of length m.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).